# Time Stretching using OpenAL

Tags: audio, audio-streaming, audio-recording, openal

Does OpenAL support Time stretching of audio without changing pitch? If not how can one achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think OpenAL supports this by itself.  Getting it to work on the fly can be a little tricky too because, naturally, stretching/compressing an audio segment changes the number of audio frames in the segment.  Still it's do-able.

I recommend the [SoundTouch library](http://www.surina.net/soundtouch/).  This Open Source library is used in the audio editing program [Audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/) to provide stretching and compressing.  You'll feed samples into the library and get samples back.  Then you'll put those into in-memory chunks to feed into OpenAL.